# Using C-style arrays as backend for STL string operations

Tags: c++, regex, string, stl

I'm writing a library to read some specific file formats. The file are being read with memory mapped files (`boost::interprocess` templates). On these files I have to do some searches with `std::regex`. To avoid unnecessary copying I want to use the memory mapped file directly (as C-style char array).

After some research time I come up with the following two approaches:

- Using the `pubsetbuf` method of a `streambuf` object
- Using the `char*` pointer as iterator

but since the implementation of the first one is optional for the STL vendor, I'm sticked with the second approach. Since the constructor for `std::string::iterator` is declared as private and the whole iterator implementation seems to be also vendor specific. I wrote my own iterator:

```
template<typename T>
class PointerIterator: std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T> {
public:
    PointerIterator(T* first, std::size_t count): first_(first), last_(first + count) {}
    PointerIterator(T* first, T* last): first_(first), last_(last) {}

    class iterator {
    public:
        iterator(T* p): ptr_(p) {}
        iterator(const iterator& it): ptr_(it.ptr_) {}
        iterator& operator++() {
            ++ptr_;
            return *this;
        }
        iterator operator++(int) {
            iterator temp(*this);
            ++ptr_;
            return temp;
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator& it) { return ptr_ == it.ptr_; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& it) { return ptr_ != it.ptr_; }
        T& operator*() { return *ptr_; }
    private:
        T* ptr_;
    };    
    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(first_);
    }
    iterator end() {
        return iterator(last_);
    }
private:
    T* first_;
    T* last_;
};
```

The iterator is working, but for use with the `std::regex_search` method (or other char-related STL methods) it must be of the same type as the STL iterators.

Is there some generic approach to cast my iterators to the STL ones (portable over STL implementations) or achieve the entire thng with another approach I didn't mentioned?

**Edit:**

The source using `std::regex_search`:

```
std::regex re(...);
boost::interprocess::mapped_region region(...);
char* first = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());
char* last = first + 5000;

// ...

PointerIterator<char> wrapper(first, last);
std::smatch match;
while (std::regex_search(wrapper.begin(), wrapper.end(), match, re)) {  // Error: No matching function call to 'regex_search'
     // do something
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "but for use with the std::regex_search method [...] it must be of the same type as the STL iterators" could you please elaborate on that? The Standard Library functions are mostly *generic*, accepting any type that meets the Iterator requirements. Also, there's a [`regex_search` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) that accepts a `char const*` (as haystack).

Comment: why can't you use the `char*` pointers as iterators directly?

Comment: @DyP I was about to ask the same thing. Since pointers satisfy the requirements of bidirectional iterators the problem has to be in the usage of `regex_search` and wrapping them in an interator class seems unnecessary.

Comment: @DyP The strings in the file are not zero-terminated and I can't add a '\0' without copying the strings. The problem with the regex_search is that no overloaded version accepts my iterators and I had no luck in finding the correct type in my STLs implementation (LLVM Compiler 4.2 shipped with Xcode on OS X)

Comment: You don't need to wrap the pointers in a class because pointers satisfy all the iterator requirements for `std::regex_search`. Just pass your first and last pointers as the `begin` and `end` parameters.

Comment: As David Brown says; the "first pointer" is the pointer to the first element of the string, the "last pointer" is the pointer one past the last element of the string.

Comment: @Stefan You need to include the code that _uses_ `regex_search` since that appears to be where the actual problem is.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I've updated the post with some sample source.

Comment: @DavidBrown Can you give an example for that approach since with method signature `regex_search(char*, char*, smatch, regex)` I'm getting the same compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `std::smatch` is a specialization of `std::match_results`. This specialization uses `string::const_iterator` as the iterator type in the template arguments passed to `std::match_results`. This requires the begin and end arguments passed to `std::regex_search` to also be of type `string::const_iterator`.

In C++ pointers satisfy the requirements of bidirectional iterators and it is not necessary to wrap them in an iterator class. If you need to search through a buffer pointed to by a `char` pointer you can either use `std::cmatch` or use `std::match_results` and specify the iterator type explicitly. In the following two examples I have retained the use of `PointerIterator` to provide solutions that directly apply to your current code base. I have also included a stand alone example you can reference in the event you want to eliminate the use of your custom iterator class.

```
PointerIterator<char> wrapper(first, last);
std::cmatch match; // <<--

while (std::regex_search(wrapper.begin(), wrapper.end(), match, re))
{
    // do something
}
```

...using `std::match_results` instead.

```
PointerIterator<char> wrapper(first, last);
std::match_results<const char*> match; // <<--

while (std::regex_search(wrapper.begin(), wrapper.end(), match, re))
{
    // do something
}
```

Below is a stand alone example that should provide a bit of codified clarification. It is based on the example on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) and uses `const char*` instead of `std::string` as the search target.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const char *haystack = "Roses are #ff0000";
    const int size = strlen(haystack);

    std::regex pattern(
        "#([a-f0-9]{2})"
        "([a-f0-9]{2})"
        "([a-f0-9]{2})");

    std::cmatch results;

    std::regex_search(haystack, haystack + size, results, pattern);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
        std::csub_match  sub_match = results[i];
        std::string sub_match_str = sub_match.str();
        std::cout << i << ": " << sub_match_str << '\n';
    }  
}
```

This produces the following output.

> 0: #ff0000
>   1: ff
>   2: 00
>   3: 00

Comment: Thanks. It worked, doesn't worried much about `smatch` since I used it that way in other projects. Now I get also the version of David without any iterator objects - simply with pointers. Understanding all of the STL is really a lifelong task.